# How to resolve UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning?

Tags: mysql, node.js, unhandled-promise-rejection

Hello and good day to you.

I have a problem. I can register a user, but when I log-in that user, it loads forever and displays an: **"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"**

**So this is the content of my users table.**
[image]

**Structure of the Users Table**
[image]

**The UnhandledPromiseRejection error**
[image]

**Basically, it says that I have a problem on my controllers/auth.js, on line 30.**
[image]

**This is my full code on auth.js.**

```
exports.signin = (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {email, password} = req.body;
        if(!email || !password) {
            return res.send("<script> alert('Provide an email and/or Password'); window.location='/signin'; </script>");
        }
        con.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], async (error, results) => {
            console.log(results);
            if(!results || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password))) {
                return res.send("<script> alert('Email or Password is incorrect'); window.location='/signin'; </script>");
            }
            else {
                const id = results[0].id;
                const token = jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
                    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
                });

                console.log("The token is: " + token);
                const cookieOptions = {
                    expires: new Date(
                        Date.now() = process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
                    ),
                    httpOnly: true
                }
                res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);
                res.status(200).redirect("/profile");
            }
        });
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

exports.signup = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);

    const {name, email, password, passwordConfirm} = req.body;
    con.query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], async (error, results) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        if(results.length > 0) {
            return res.send("<script> alert('This email is already in use or invalid.'); window.location='/signup'; </script>");
        }
        else if(password !== passwordConfirm) {
            return res.send("<script> alert('Passwords do not match.'); window.location='/signup'; </script>");         
        }

        let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 8);
        console.log(hashedPassword);

        con.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', {name: name, email: email, password: hashedPassword}, (error, results) => {
            if(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
            else {
                console.log(results);
                return res.send("<script> alert('USER IS REGISTERED! You are redirected to Sign-in Page.'); window.location='/signin'; </script>");      
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**I watched his channel and copied the code.**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VavWEtI5T7c&ab_channel=TelmoSampaio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the following line:

```
expires: new Date(Date.now() = process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
```

You are trying to assign a value, but it probably should be an addition of the expiration to the current date:

```
expires: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
```

Comment: you're right, it was trying to assign a value. it should've been "addition". Thank you! It now works.